# Send parameter data value array in vue js and backend laravel not work

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, laravel-api

I found a problem when sending the value array to the backend, on the backend I have set it to accept the value array. but when i checked on postman the function was running successfully. but when I implement it on the front end where I use vuejs the function doesn't work.
the message that the server sends when the backend hits the api is as shown below.

[image]

I find it difficult to pass the parameter value array in this case. whether there was an error when I threw the value. thank you for helping me

CODE BACKEND method POST

```
public function storeInsert(Request $request)
    {
       
        $data= $request->get('data');
        $response =  gradingakhir::insert(json_decode($data, true)); // Eloquent approach
         return response()->json([
            'code' => 1,
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Data berhasil ditambah!',
            'data' => $data
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    } 


#FONT END CODE

var params = {
        data: this.dataStoreGradding,
      }
      console.log(this.dataStoreGradding)
      console.log(params)

      const res = await apiService.postGradingAkhir(params).then(res => res)

# CODE SERVICE HIT FRONT END TO BACKEND
  postGradingAkhir(param) {
    const url = `${API_URL_DEV}post-grading-akhir`
    options.headers.Authorization = 'bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
    const data = axios
      .post(url, param, options)
      .then(response => response.data)
      .catch(err => err)
    return data
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send the array via FormData this way:

```js
    let params = new FormData;
    let arr = ['this', 'is', 'an', 'array'];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      params.append('arr[]', arr[i]);
    }
      postGradingAkhir(params) {
        const url = `${API_URL_DEV}post-grading-akhir`
        options.headers.Authorization = 'bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        const data = axios
          .post(url, params, options)
          .then(response => response.data)
          .catch(err => err)
        return data
      }
```